# Nextjs, catchall, static generation and redirects

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, http-status-code-301, getstaticprops, ssg

I have a website using nextjs 10.1

I am using SSG and a catchall strategy, i.e. under /pages, I have

```
-pages
--[...slug]
---index.tsx
```

and in my index.tsx I have

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context: any) => {
const { params, locale } = context;
const slug = params.slug;
//multiple slugs can lead to the same page
...
}

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
...
return {
    paths,
    // Fallback blocking ensures that pages not listed in getStaticPath will still be rendered with a call to getStaticProps
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
}
```

In my headless cms (primic), slug history is saved (which is quite useful) and then multiple slugs an lead to the same page beacause I also parametered fall
As of today, the right canonical tag is rendered for those multiple versions, with a link to the last slug parametered on prismic.

I would prefer a 301.

How can I create a 301 from my getStaticProps or how can I structure my /pages/[catchall] so that I have 301 from old slugs to new ones?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: If you know the redirects at build-time you should use [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) in your `next.config.js`.

Comment: I don't know them at build time because content can be changed on the cms an any time... already using that for other redirects